# Absolutely Positioned Element Disappears in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.NET page that has an absolutely positioned span which acts as a button for hiding a div. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but it disappears in IE. I copied the same HTML structure and CSS to a text editor using normal HTML (not web forms) and it doesn't disappear.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Instructions</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            *
            {
                margin:0;
                outline:0;
                padding:0
            }

            body
            {
                font:normal 12px/1.4 Sans-Serif
            }

            #wrapper
            {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:940px
            }

            .instructions-container
            {
                overflow:hidden;
                position:relative
            }

            .instructions
            {
                border:3px solid #eee;
                margin:10px 0 0;
                padding:7px;
                position:relative
            }

            .hide-instructions
            {
                background:url(../images/icon/cancel.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 red;
                cursor:pointer;
                display:block;
                height:16px;
                position:absolute;
                right:7px;
                top:7px;
                width:16px;
                zoom:1
            }

            .show-instructions
            {
                background:#eee;
                display:none;
                color:#666;
                float:right;
                padding:10px;
                text-decoration:none
            }

            .show-instructions:hover
            {
                background:#ccc
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                InitializeInstructions();
            });

            function InitializeInstructions() {
                var instructions = $('.instructions'),
                    hide = $('.hide-instructions'),
                    show = $('.show-instructions');

                instructions.hide();
                show.show();

                hide.click(function () {
                    instructions.slideUp('slow');
                    show.slideDown('fast');
                });

                show.click(function () {
                    instructions.slideDown('slow');
                    show.slideUp('fast');
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="instructions-container">
                <div class="instructions">
                    <h2>
                        Instructions
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Nulla vehicula volutpat nibh at semper. Praesent sem odio, dignissim eget scelerisque ut, ornare in enim. 
                        Fusce pellentesque rhoncus egestas. Vestibulum lobortis nunc ligula, a elementum ligula. Pellentesque luctus 
                        convallis sagittis. Nunc ut justo vitae elit luctus cursus a sed odio. Nam nec consectetur neque.
                    </p>
                    <span class="hide-instructions"></span>
                </div>
                <a class="show-instructions" href="#">
                    Show Instructions
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click on **a.show-instructions**, the div.instructions appears along with **span.hide-instructions**. Thing is, it disappears after the div has finished sliding.

I really don't understand why **span.hide-instructions** disappears when it's in an aspx page; the code is the same. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:
The span reappears when you try to highlight text and hover over the blue thingy in IE8**

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: IE8 (annoying minimum number of characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `z-index` property. Might be a layer problem. So your `.hide-instructions` shall look like this:

```
.hide-instructions
        {
            background:url(../images/icon/cancel.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 red;
            cursor:pointer;
            display:block;
            height:16px;
            position:absolute;
            right:7px;
            top:7px;
            width:16px;
            zoom:1;
            z-index: 10000; /* Added a lot, because you never know */
        }
```

Comment: Hi, @Troy Tried it but the span still disappears.

Comment: Do you have any jQuery running on the same page? Because it can be a `setTimeout()` hiding it in an amount of time.

Comment: I do, but i don't think that that's what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to your element that is disappearing, this is an ie-quirk.

overflow: visible!important;

That should do it.